# How to increase LVL cache-valid time?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I've implemented LVL server managed policy in my app. I know that lvl server response is cached in a device for some period of time so users are able to use a app without interent connection (lvl uses cached license then). I would like to know exactly how long that period is and how I can increase it. 
Basically, lvl I've implemented checks license everytime the app starts and I would like to increase cache-valid time to 60 days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't found the actual value of the lvl cache-time set by google servers, but I found how to change it. In the `ServerManagedPolicy.java` file change:

```
setValidityTimestamp(extras.get("VT"));
```

to whatever you like (here to 30 days):

```
setValidityTimestamp(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + (MILLIS_PER_MINUTE * 60 *24*30)));
```

Comment: Hoy do you change this class? Where is it located? I tried to change the.class in the .jar file but no success.

Comment: You have to download the LVL library and import it as a library project into your workspace. All is described here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#download-lvl .Then you can change the cache vaild time in `ServerManagedPolicy.java` as I've described above.

Answer (score 1):

replace in ServerManagedPolicy.java

```
setValidityTimestamp(extras.get("VT"));
```

to

```
setValidityTimestamp(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + (MILLIS_PER_MINUTE * 60 * 24 * 30 * 3)));
```

**MILLIS_PER_MINUTE** gives you output 60000:

60000 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 3 = 7776000000 millis, or 90 days

return remaining time in days back to user:

```
(mValidityTimestamp - System.currentTimeMillis())/(60*60*24*1000)
```

I am using SharedPreferences to write the data and return back to user **DAYS** until next binding and checking of license